# Photo synth 3d walk in three js or babylon js

Tags: three.js, babylonjs

Photo synth has an effect called "walk" not in the older version but in the newer one.  Using a sequence of about 6 images I can create the effect that the user is walking in the scene.  The software says it uses photogrammetry to create a 3d scene but from looking at the downloaded code it is just the images sliced up.  Is there away I can recreate this effect in three js or babylon js?  Using a blend from one picture to another?

I'm attaching a picture of the geometry the photo synth adds as it moves from one image to another.

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @imudin07 No nothing.  Photo synth is also retired from Microsoft so unless it is done with a camera that uses 3d it doesn't seem too feasible.  There is ways to recreate 3d scenes using photographs (photogrammetry) but the results for me were not too good.